# How do I avoid overlapping bars in a columnrange chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have the following `columnrange` chart: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2a2asax2/1

My problem is, that some of the columns in the "closed" category are plotted on top of each other. How do I separate them, so that they are printed underneath each other instead?

[image]

Comment: In your problem , all the bars of closed category having same x, that's why overlapping happening.While in Active category ,all x are distinct See http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2a2asax2/2/

Comment: Hmm, but I need to have the defined x values, they are important to understand the graph!

Comment: But when all points which you define, have the same x, then are printed in the same place. It makes sense. Change x value if you need to display them side by side.

Comment: okay, I get it, the graph is simple not made for this :-)